# Dimension and separability of $\ell^2(I)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let $\ell^2(I)= \left\{ x:I\rightarrow \mathbb C\mid \sum _{i\in I} |x_i|^2<\infty \right\} $ with inner product $\sum_{i\in I}x_i \bar y_i$.

I am supposed to find the dimension of this space and for which sets it is separable.

I don't really understand what's going on with the set $I$, but I'm guessing the dimension would just be $|I|$ since the dimension of the usual $\ell^2$ of absolutely summable sequences of complex numbers is of dimension $\aleph _0$. I really don't know how to prove this though - my only intuition is to define a tentative basis $e_i:I\rightarrow \mathbb C$ as just $\delta _i$. For separability, I'm not sure but I think the space can only be separable for $|I|=\aleph _0$.

Comment: 3 cases : $I$ is finite and $l^2(I)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{C}^n,\|.\|_2)$. Second case $I$ is countably infinite (there is a bijection $I \to \mathbb{N}$) and $l^2(I)$ is isomorphic to $l^2(\mathbb{N})$. Third case $I$ is uncountably infinite, and $l^2(I)$ is not seperable (if I remember correctly, in this latter case $\sum_{i \in I} |x_i|^2$ should be replaced by $\sum_{i \in I, x_i \ne 0} |x_i|^2$, since $\{i \in I \ \mid \ x_i \ne 0\}$ has to be countable, even if $I$ is not countable)